# Complex Analysis: Extension

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I am thinking about something like this:

In complex numbers every polynomial of degree n has exactly n roots. But, here is the trouble: n is a finite number. So, we have the theorem for polynomials of a finite power. But, for power $+\infty$ this is far from being true. Simple counterexample is: we know that there is no such z, that $e^z$ is zero. As the definition of the exponential function says, it is the series: $\sum_0^{+\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ (1) so, we have that polynomial (1) has no zero!

So, does it make any sense to expand complex numbers with numbers for which even infinite series have zeros??

Comment: So you're asking if there is an extension of the complex numbers (in a similar way that the complex numbers are an extension of the real numbers) for which every function defined by a power series has a zero?

Comment: Yes, and if it doesn't exist, does it makes sense that we build it.

Comment: Well, there's a good reason $\exp(z)$ is never zero: $\exp(z) \exp(-z) = 1$.  Any "extension" in which $\exp$ acquires a zero is going to have some strange algebra...

Comment: We will define that exp($+\infty) = +\infty$ and problem solved. Because in a complex analysis we have a single +$\infty$ which is a regular dot in complex field, so we will map that way and problem solved.